# Code letters as numbers

Tags: bash

The script bellow is asking the user to enter something then it print the entry as an output:

```
#!/bin/bash
 printf "\e[31mType/Enter something: $pdir\e[m  ";
 read -e userInput
 if [[ -n "$userInput" ]]
 then
     pdir=$userInput 
 fi
 printf "\e[96mYour code is: $pdir\e[m\n";
```

**My questions are:**

1. How can the previous code read only letters in "userInput"?
2. How can I convert my entry "userInput" as an output numbers for example if I enter "John" how can I get an output numbers.

Comment: You'll have to describe the algorithm you're using to convert letters to numbers.

Comment: @glennjackman. Kindly do you know any reference that can help me in this

Comment: @goro the obvious one would be to convert all letters to their unicode numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways that come to mind

convert each character to its ASCII value

```
$ echo John | perl -lne 'printf "%03d", ord for split ""'
074111104110
```

Or, if you don't strictly need *numbers*, just a code, base64

```
$ echo John | base64
Sm9obgo=
```

---

To decode:

```
$ echo 074111104110 | perl -ne 'print chr for /(\d{3})/g'
John

$ echo Sm9obgo= | base64 --decode
John
```

Comment: Thanks! Kindly what 'say unpack "W*"' is referring to ?

Comment: `echo John | md5sum | tr -d '[:alpha:]' | sed 's/-//'`

Comment: @goro I removed that `unpack` answer -- frankly, I've never been able to wrap my head around pack and unpack.

Comment: [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack) and [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) are for working with binary formats.

Comment: You can also use `xxd -ps` and `xxd -ps -r`.